# Noise function outputs subtly different result when converted from hlsl to c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, simplex-noise

I am making a game in which I procedurally generate planets using a compute shader which builds a deformed sphere based on noise from a noise function I downloaded. The whole system works fine in the shader. I however wanted to be able to sample the noise function in c# without having to interact with the GPU, so I have attempted to convert the function into something that works in c#, it appears to work at first glance and functions perfectly as simplex noise but it is consistently different in shape to the GPU version. I am not sure if I have some math the wrong way around somewhere or indeed any idea as to what the issue might be.

[Image of both results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hyHi.png)

Here is the code for the function in HLSL

```
float3 mod289(float3 x)
{
    return x - floor(x / 289.0) * 289.0;
}

float4 mod289(float4 x)
{
    return x - floor(x / 289.0) * 289.0;
}

float4 permute(float4 x)
{
    return mod289((x * 34.0 + 1.0) * x);
}

float4 taylorInvSqrt(float4 r)
{
    return 1.79284291400159 - r * 0.85373472095314;
}

float snoise(float3 v)
{
    const float2 C = float2(1.0 / 6.0, 1.0 / 3.0);

    // First corner
    float3 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yyy));
    float3 x0 = (v   - i) + dot(i, C.xxx);

    // Other corners
    float3 g = step(x0.yzx, x0);
    float3 l = 1.0 - g;
    float3 i1 = min(g, l.zxy);
    float3 i2 = max(g, l.zxy);

    // x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;
    // x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;
    // x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;
    float3 x1 = x0 - i1 + C.xxx;
    float3 x2 = x0 - i2 + C.yyy;
    float3 x3 = x0 - 0.5;

    // Permutations
    i = mod289(i); // Avoid truncation effects in permutation
    float4 p =
      permute(permute(permute(i.z + float4(0.0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0))
                            + i.y + float4(0.0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0))
                            + i.x + float4(0.0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0));

    // Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.
    // The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)
    float4 j = p - 49.0 * floor(p / 49.0);  // mod(p,7*7)

    float4 x_ = floor(j / 7.0);
    float4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0 * x_);  // mod(j,N)

    float4 x = (x_ * 2.0 + 0.5) / 7.0 - 1.0;
    float4 y = (y_ * 2.0 + 0.5) / 7.0 - 1.0;

    float4 h = 1.0 - abs(x) - abs(y);

    float4 b0 = float4(x.xy, y.xy);
    float4 b1 = float4(x.zw, y.zw);

    //float4 s0 = float4(lessThan(b0, 0.0)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    //float4 s1 = float4(lessThan(b1, 0.0)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float4 s0 = floor(b0) * 2.0 + 1.0;
    float4 s1 = floor(b1) * 2.0 + 1.0;
    float4 sh = -step(h, 0.0);

    float4 a0 = b0.xzyw + s0.xzyw * sh.xxyy;
    float4 a1 = b1.xzyw + s1.xzyw * sh.zzww;

    float3 g0 = float3(a0.xy, h.x);
    float3 g1 = float3(a0.zw, h.y);
    float3 g2 = float3(a1.xy, h.z);
    float3 g3 = float3(a1.zw, h.w);

    // Normalise gradients
    float4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(float4(dot(g0, g0), dot(g1, g1), dot(g2, g2), dot(g3, g3)));
    g0 *= norm.x;
    g1 *= norm.y;
    g2 *= norm.z;
    g3 *= norm.w;

    // Mix final noise value
    float4 m = max(0.6 - float4(dot(x0, x0), dot(x1, x1), dot(x2, x2), dot(x3, x3)), 0.0);
    m = m * m;
    m = m * m;

    float4 px = float4(dot(x0, g0), dot(x1, g1), dot(x2, g2), dot(x3, g3));
    return 42.0 * dot(m, px);
}
```

And Here is my attempt to adapt it into something that can be sampled in c#. I am aware that this is far from ideal formatting but I was attempting to do a one to one conversion and was not really paying too much attention to best practices.

```
using UnityEngine;
using float4 = UnityEngine.Vector4;
using float3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;
using float2 = UnityEngine.Vector2;

public static class NoiseLibrary
{
    private static readonly float2 C = new float2(1.0f / 6.0f, 1.0f / 3.0f);

    private static float4 floor(float4 input)
    {
        return new float4(Mathf.Floor(input.x), Mathf.Floor(input.y), Mathf.Floor(input.z), Mathf.Floor(input.w));
    }

    private static float3 floor(float3 input)
    {
        return new float3(Mathf.Floor(input.x), Mathf.Floor(input.y), Mathf.Floor(input.z));
    }

    private static float4 scale(float4 a, float4 b)
    {
        return new float4(a.x * b.x, a.y * b.y, a.z * b.z, a.w * b.w);
    }

    private static float3 mod289(float3 x)
    {
        return x - floor(x / 289.0f) * 289.0f;
    }

    private static float4 mod289(float4 x)
    {
        return x - floor(x / 289.0f) * 289.0f;
    }

    private static float4 permute(float4 x)
    {
        return mod289(scale((x * 34.0f + float4.one), x));
    }

    private static float4 taylorInvSqrt(float4 r)
    {
        return (float4.one * 1.79284291400159f) - r * 0.85373472095314f;
    }

    private static float dot(float3 a, float3 b)
    {
        return float3.Dot(a, b);
    }

    private static float3 xxx(float3 input)
    {
        return new float3(input.x, input.x, input.x);
    }

    private static float3 yyy(float3 input)
    {
        return new float3(input.y, input.y, input.y);
    }

    private static float3 yzx(float3 input)
    {
        return new float3(input.y, input.z, input.x);
    }

    private static float3 zxy(float3 input)
    {
        return new float3(input.z, input.x, input.y);
    }

    private static float3 add(float a, float3 b)
    {
        return float3.one * a + b;
    }

    private static float3 add(float3 b, float a)
    {
        return float3.one * a + b;
    }

    private static float4 add(float a, float4 b)
    {
        return float4.one * a + b;
    }

    private static float4 add(float4 b, float a)
    {
        return float4.one * a + b;
    }

    private static float3 step(float3 a, float3 x)
    {
        return new float3(x.x > a.x ? 1 : 0, x.y > a.y ? 1 : 0, x.z > a.z ? 1 : 0);
    }

    private static float3 min(float3 a, float3 b)
    {
        return new float3(Mathf.Min(a.x, b.x), Mathf.Min(a.y, b.y), Mathf.Min(a.z, b.z));
    }

    private static float3 max(float3 a, float3 b)
    {
        return new float3(Mathf.Max(a.x, b.x), Mathf.Max(a.y, b.y), Mathf.Max(a.z, b.z));
    }

    private static float4 max(float4 a, float4 b)
    {
        return new float4(Mathf.Max(a.x, b.x), Mathf.Max(a.y, b.y), Mathf.Max(a.z, b.z), Mathf.Max(a.w, b.w));
    }

    private static float4 abs(float4 a)
    {
        return new float4(Mathf.Abs(a.x), Mathf.Abs(a.y), Mathf.Abs(a.z), Mathf.Abs(a.w));
    }

    private static float4 xzyw(float4 input)
    {
        return new float4(input.x, input.z, input.y, input.w);
    }

    private static float4 xxyy(float4 input)
    {
        return new float4(input.x, input.x, input.y, input.y);
    }

    private static float4 zzww(float4 input)
    {
        return new float4(input.z, input.z, input.w, input.w);
    }

    private static float dot(float4 a, float4 b)
    {
        return float4.Dot(a, b);
    }

    private static float4 step(float4 a, float4 x)
    {
        return new float4(x.x > a.x ? 1 : 0, x.y > a.y ? 1 : 0, x.z > a.z ? 1 : 0, x.w > a.w ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public static float snoise(float3 v)
    {
        // First corner
        float3 i = floor(add(dot(v, yyy(C)), v));
        float3 x0 = add(v - i, dot(i, xxx(C)));

        // Other corners
        float3 g = step(yzx(x0), x0);
        float3 l = float3.one - g;
        float3 i1 = min(g, zxy(l));
        float3 i2 = max(g, zxy(l));

        // x1 = x0 - i1  + 1.0 * C.xxx;
        // x2 = x0 - i2  + 2.0 * C.xxx;
        // x3 = x0 - 1.0 + 3.0 * C.xxx;
        float3 x1 = x0 - i1 + xxx(C);
        float3 x2 = x0 - i2 + yyy(C);
        float3 x3 = x0 - (float3.one * 0.5f);

        // Permutations
        i = mod289(i); // Avoid truncation effects in permutation

        float4 p =
          permute(add(permute(add(permute(add(i.z, new float4(0, i1.z, i2.z, 1.0f))), i.y) + new float4(0, i1.y, i2.y, 1.0f)), i.x) + new float4(0, i1.x, i2.x, 1.0f));

        // Gradients: 7x7 points over a square, mapped onto an octahedron.
        // The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 49 (49*6 = 294)
        float4 j = p - 49.0f * floor(p / 49.0f);  // mod(p,7*7)

        float4 x_ = floor(j / 7.0f);
        float4 y_ = floor(j - 7.0f * x_);  // mod(j,N)

        float4 x = add(add(x_ * 2.0f, 0.5f) / 7.0f, -1.0f);
        float4 y = add(add(y_ * 2.0f, 0.5f) / 7.0f, -1.0f);

        float4 h = float4.one - abs(x) - abs(y);

        float4 b0 = new float4(x.x, x.y, y.x, y.y);
        float4 b1 = new float4(x.z, x.w, y.z, y.w);

        //float4 s0 = float4(lessThan(b0, 0.0)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        //float4 s1 = float4(lessThan(b1, 0.0)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
        float4 s0 = floor(b0) * 2.0f + float4.one;
        float4 s1 = floor(b1) * 2.0f + float4.one;
        float4 sh = -step(h, float4.zero);

        float4 a0 = xzyw(b0) + scale(xzyw(s0), xxyy(sh));
        float4 a1 = xzyw(b1) + scale(xzyw(s1), zzww(sh));

        float3 g0 = new float3(a0.x, a0.y, h.x);
        float3 g1 = new float3(a0.z, a0.w, h.y);
        float3 g2 = new float3(a1.x, a1.y, h.z);
        float3 g3 = new float3(a1.z, a1.w, h.w);

        // Normalise gradients
        float4 norm = taylorInvSqrt(new float4(dot(g0, g0), dot(g1, g1), dot(g2, g2), dot(g3, g3)));
        g0 *= norm.x;
        g1 *= norm.y;
        g2 *= norm.z;
        g3 *= norm.w;

        // Mix final noise value
        float4 m = max((float4.one * 0.6f) - new float4(dot(x0, x0), dot(x1, x1), dot(x2, x2), dot(x3, x3)), float4.zero);
        m = scale(m, m);
        m = scale(m, m);

        float4 px = new float4(dot(x0, g0), dot(x1, g1), dot(x2, g2), dot(x3, g3));
        return 42.0f * dot(m, px);
    }
}
```

At first I thought I may have gotten the different vector types confused in the different functions and I went through to make sure that all of them match. The result is still a perfectly working noise function, but I need it to be the same as the one produced by the gpu.

As an addendum: the reason i redefined the unity vectors to be float2, float3, and float4 was because i was having issues with visual studio's find and replace feature but that should have no bearing on the code or the result.

Comment: There might be minor numerical differences between hardware, compilers etc, when using floating point numbers. Such minor numerical differences might become significant when dealing with chaotic things like noise.

Comment: It may also be that some of the C# `float` calculations are being performed using double or higher precision precision, then rounded at the end, rather than being performed entirely using `float` precision.  From the C# language spec [8.3.7 Floating-point types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#837-floating-point-types): *Floating-point operations may be performed with higher precision than the result type of the operation...*

Comment: and subsequently *Some hardware architectures support an “extended” or “long double” floating-point type with greater range and precision than the double type, and implicitly perform all floating-point operations using this higher precision type... rather than require an implementation to forfeit both performance and precision, C# allows a higher precision type to be used for all floating-point operations.*

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to make this work, if anyone runs into a similar issue [This Noise Library](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/simple-3d-noise-79407) on the Unity asset store can be made to perform the same function with minimal modification, and is what I would recommend looking into if anyone has similar needs.